# How to fix Module parse failed: Unexpected token?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-router, node-modules

When I run `npm run build` I got this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/client.js 7:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:2)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/jshint-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| const component = (
>   <Router history={browserHistory}>
|     {routes}
|   </Router>
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./src/client.js main[1]
```

**./src/client.js** (with warning for `browserHistory` -- Cannot resolve symbol 'browserHistory' )

```
import React      from 'react';
import ReactDOM   from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory, Router } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

const component = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    {routes}
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('react-view'));
```

How can I fix it?

> react: 16.13.0
>
> webpack: 4.42.0
>
> npm: 6.14.2

**webpack-config.js**

```js
global.Promise         = require('bluebird');
const webpack            = require('webpack');
const path               = require('path');

const plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      BROWSER:  JSON.stringify(true),
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }
  })
];

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/client.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/, // include .js files
      enforce: "pre", // preload the jshint loader
      exclude: /node_modules/, // exclude any and all files in the node_modules folder
      use: [{
        loader: "jshint-loader",
        // more options in the optional jshint object
        options: {  // ⬅ formally jshint property
          camelcase: true,
          emitErrors: false,
          failOnHint: false
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: what is your webpack config?

Comment: @tudor.gergely I added to post, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpack config doesn't handle React's JSX syntax. You need to update it with some loaders for this to work (here's a tutorial: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/)

I would recommend you use create-react-app at first, which abstracts all those configurations away: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app . It is way easier to get started with react this way and you can customise it when you're ready/if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following setting for the use property. Notice that options include presets @babel/preset-react because you're bundling JSX files

```
use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
     },
```