# Unable to load styles after adding the app in npm package manager

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

I've added my app in npm packages using `npm publish`, and I'm getting this error while using the component in a project:

```js
error - ./node_modules/react-gsap-debugging/src/gsap-debugging.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (67:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|   return (
>       <div className={styles.control_panel}>
|         <div className={styles.control_panel_flex}>
|           <input
```

Source code: https://github.com/EliseiNicolae/react-gsap-debugging
Npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gsap-debugging

How can I load the styles in my component?

Comment: > https://stackoverflow.com/a/72625035/11950988
hope this helps ____________